# Store and retrieve and display current date and time in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

My title says it all, how best can i store current date and time in a sqlite database and retrieve and display the way i want like 3:45 pm, 20th Jan, 2014 in android?

Comment: You typically save it as an ISO string ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). Then you can use a SimpleDateFormatter to format the DateTime string as you like.

Comment: could you please provide a source code

Comment: SimpleDateFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Code sample: http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/

Comment: I would prefer to save the unix time as an integer (long in java). String works fine, but if you save it as an integer you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Calendar object and store it as a long.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // returns Calendar object set to current moment

// store in database: use your own Database class constructor, not "Database(context)"
SQLiteDatabase db = new Database(context).getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("my date column", cal.getTimeInMillis());
db.insert("my table", null, cv);
db.close();

// to retrieve date after using the cursor to get values from database:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("my date column"))); //resets the calendar object to the time stored from database

// display time in log
Log.d("The time is: ", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
// the +1 on the month field is because January starts at 0.
```